# backbone.js doesn't fire my events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am writing a backbone.js app, and I have a problem. 
My collections do not fire events, can anyone spot the problem in the code bellow? I get the render-feedback, the initializer feedback.. but the append method is never called. I know that the "../app" returns a list with tro json items. And I can even see that these are being created in the collection.
Why do my event not get called?

```
window.TablesInspectorView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: "div",

    initialize: function () {
        console.log('Initializing window.TablesInspectorView');        

        // setup the tables
        this.data     = new Backbone.Collection();
        this.data.url = "../app";
        this.data.fetch();

        // some event binds..
        this.data.on("change", this.render     , this);
        this.data.on("add"   , this.append_item, this);
    },
    render: function(){
        console.log("render");
        _.each(this.data.models, this.append_item);
    },
    append_item: function(item) {
        console.log("appended");
    }
});
```

Comment: When you fetch a collection you will get a 'reset' event, not 'add'.

Comment: Have you tried binding the events before you call the fetch method?

Comment: @paulHoenecke: your right except that the 'reset' event replaces 'change' .. but that does not fix the problem -- the add event should still be fired once for every item in the collection..

Comment: @Corey, since the render  method is called after the initialize method is finished, this should make no difference -- also there is no parallel processes is JS... which i think means that the fetch's ajax call will not fire before after the initialize method has finished.

Comment: You will not get 'add' events, only 'reset'.  Look at backbone source.  Fetch calls `reset` by default, and in `reset` you can see it is adding to the collection with option `silent:true`.  Then a single 'reset' event is triggered.

Comment: You can try using the update fetch, by using `this.data.fetch({update:true})` which would give you 'add' events.  But @Corey is right, you should bind to the events before calling fetch if your API is synchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my knowledge , the backbone fetch() is an asynchronous event and when it completes the **reset**  event is triggered ,

When the models belonging to the collection (this.data) are modified , the **change** event is triggered, so im guessing you have not got that part correct.

so i would do something like this :

```
window.TablesInspectorView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: "div",

    initialize: function () {
        console.log('Initializing window.TablesInspectorView');        

        // setup the tables
        this.data     = new Backbone.Collection();
        this.data.url = "../app";
        this.data.fetch();

        // some event binds..
        this.data.on("reset", this.render     , this); //change here
        this.data.on("add"   , this.append_item, this); // i dont see a this.data.add() in you code so assuming this was never called ?
    },
    render: function(){
        console.log("render");
        _.each(this.data.models, this.append_item);
    },
    append_item: function(item) {
        console.log("appended");
    }
});
```

Comment: The response regarding the "reset" event is right, but I have some comments... You should not access the models attribute directly, Collections proxies most of underscore methods therefore you can do this.data.each(this.append_item); Once the fetch() is done and the reset event is triggered you can use that event to render your views (but not add the items to the collection as they are already there), I do not understand why to add items to a collection on the render.